# How to repaint/call again paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

So I have this code:

```
public class myPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    int x = 0;
    JButton myButton = new JButton("Click me");

    public myPanel(){
    super().setLayout(null);
    myButton.setBounds(50,50,50,50);
    super().add(myButton);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(x==1)
    g.drawString("hi",10,10);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==myButton){
        x=1;
        //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

How do I call paintComponent again? Say when I press the button, it calls paintComponent again and draw the string, "Hi", after checking if the integer,x, is equal to one?  Thank you in advance!!! Still very new to Java here, so can you guys explain this like you will to a 10 year old?

Comment: what about calling repaint()?

Answer (score 4):

Call `repaint()`, it will paint it again.

Answer (score 2):

You would call `repaint()` after any change in state that should change the GUI's view. For instance, if the button changes a variable, and if this should be reflected in a change in the view, call `repaint()` in the button's ActionListener. If a mouse drag changes the view of an ImageIcon sprite, then you would call repaint in the MouseMotionListener's mouseDragged method. If a Swing Timer drives an animation, then you would call `repaint()` from within the Swing Timer's ActionListener.

One thing you never want to do is to call `repaint()` from within a `paint(Graphics g)` or `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method as this will lead to looping that is completely out of your control.

On a side note, in general you will want to avoid using null layouts and setBounds as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.